# Installing Steam on Ubuntu 16.04 x64, 32 bit Package Problems

Tags: 64-bit, steam, 32-bit

When I try to install Steam on my Ubuntu 16.04 x64, I see these errors.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
steam:i386 : 
Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.3) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libxinerama1:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libtxc-dxtn0:i386

Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
steam-launcher : 
Depends: python-apt but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I try to download the 32-bit package:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

But it's not working, too:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

How can I install Steam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16.04 is new and all packages are not ready to use in all servers. Using Main Server to download packages will solve your problem.

1. System Settings
2. Software & Updates
3. Select "Main Server" from "Download from" section

Comment: Sorry! Same problem :(

Comment: @ibrahimalan then why did you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first press CTRL + ALT + T to open your terminal

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Then install steam with

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

This may not work with your setup but this worked for me.

**Note:** To report errors in steam do `steam` in your terminal and recreate what caused the error, then report it to the steam linux github, located here https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux

Comment: sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386 gives this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libbz2-1.0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.